# How to send publish json message to kafka topic using python?

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka

I have the following kafka producer:

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer

def send(self):
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=self.bootstrap_server)
    message = prepare_message()
    producer.send(self.topic, message)
    sleep(2)

def prepare_message(self):
    message = {"Topic": "Test",
               "Message": "Test"}
    return json.dumps(message)
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

How can I send a json message to kafka? If I encode the message and send that, this works. But that's not what I want to do. I want to publish a json object to kafka. How can I do that?

Any assistance on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The correction was just changing the last line of the `prepare_message` method to: `json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')`. In particular, this now works as a python kafka producer, producing json messages:

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer

def send(self):
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=self.bootstrap_server)
    message = prepare_message()
    producer.send(self.topic, message)
    sleep(2)

def prepare_message(self):
    message = {"Topic": "Test",
               "Message": "Test"}
    return json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')
```